# Transformed column to rows based on common column values in PostgreSQL 11.0

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to convert column to rows within the same table (based on common column names). I have transformed/ joined a table such that columns with same names are joined together.

```
medicinal_product_no    substance      drug_name               who_atc          medicinal_product_no    substance           drug_name                  who_atc
3297995                 azilsartan     amlodipine;azilsartan   C09DB            3297995                 amlodipine          amlodipine;azilsartan      C09DB
3876                    dexamethasone  dexamethasone           A01AC | C05AA    3876                    dexamethasone       dexamethasone              A01AC | C05AA | D07AB
```

The desired output is:

```
medicinal_product_no    substance      drug_name               who_atc          
3297995                 azilsartan     amlodipine;azilsartan   C09DB            
3297995                 amlodipine     amlodipine;azilsartan   C09DB
3876                    dexamethasone  dexamethasone           A01AC | C05AA    
3876                    dexamethasone  dexamethasone           A01AC | C05AA | D07AB
```

Comment: Can you give us the request you use? The data format you have ?

Comment: I did not get it.. I would like to join common column values (row-wise)

Comment: not knowing what the source prevent give advice. For instance perhaps a "union" is enough on your use case. perhaps you may use "transpose" ...